# Radio button returning undefined value in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

http://jsfiddle.net/jngpjbjm/

Have a look at the fiddle link attached. Radio button value is returning a undefined value. I don't why. Please help with this.

```
<input type="radio" name="arv" value="1">1
<br>
<input type="radio" name="arv" value="2">2

var radio = document.getElementsByName('arv');
radio[0].addEventListener('click', check());
radio[1].addEventListener('click', check());

function check() {
for (var i = 0; i < radio.length; i++) {
    var rcheck = radio[i].checked;
    if (!rcheck) {
        alert(rcheck.value);

    }

}
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use jquery?

Comment: Why use a whole framework for a simple onclick? In any case the () needs also to be removed from the ,click()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/jngpjbjm/3/

It should be:

`alert(radio[i].value);`

Maybe you need something like this?

`function check() {
    alert( event.target.value );
}`

http://jsfiddle.net/jngpjbjm/9/

Comment: You need tp address the wrongly assigned event handler too. Your fiddle - is event available in all browsers?

Comment: You were very close though

Comment: Second fiddle doesnt work: `ReferenceError: event is not defined`

Answer (score 2):

I have tried to remove all excessive code from your original script as being unnecessary (kind of), whats left are the bare essentials. thanks @mplungjan

Try this:

```
var radio = document.getElementsByName('arv');
// here is how to add event listeners like the pros over at MDN
radio[0].addEventListener('click', check, false);
radio[1].addEventListener('click', check, false);

  function check(e) {
//simply grab the event by passing it as "e" and capturing its target.value
        var rcheck = e.target.value;
            alert(rcheck);

    }
```

Comment: True. Perhaps mention that? And also that older IEs will not understand the addEventListener

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
var radio = document.getElementsByName('arv');
radio[0].addEventListener('click', check);
radio[1].addEventListener('click', check);

function check() {
for (var i = 0; i < radio.length; i++) {
    var rcheck = radio[i].checked;
    if (!rcheck) {
        alert(radio[i].value);

    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This version will work in all browsers.

```
window.onload=function() {
  var radios = document.getElementsByName('arv');
  for (var i=0;i<radios.length;i++) {
    radios[i].onclick=function() {
      alert(this.value);
    }
  }
}
```

[**onclick**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Older_way_to_register_event_listeners)

> Because it was essentially part of DOM 0, this method is very widely supported and requires no special cross–browser code; hence it is normally used to register event listeners dynamically unless the extra features of addEventListener() are needed.